# Printing columns 3 lines translated up and down

Tags: text-processing

I have a table

```
1 a I
2 b II
3 c III
4 d IV
5 e V
6 f VI
7 g VII
8 h VIII
9 i IX
```

I want to print **column 2 with 3 lines translated down** and **column 3 with 3 lines translated up** to have :

```
1   IV
2   V
3   VI
4 a VII
5 b VIII
6 c IX
7 d
8 e
9 f
```

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear at all as written.  Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I have added few more lines, hope it helps!

Comment: Is column 2 *actually* filled with one character wide values as shown?  If so, a Vim macro may be easiest.

Comment: There is nothing  unclear about the question.  Why put it in hold?   Instead of a knee-jerk reaction, people who put the question on hold, should have attempted to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the 6 row example originally provided (now changed):

```
$ cat infile
1 a I
2 b II
3 c III
4 d IV
5 e V
6 f VI

$ cat t.awk
{ for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) { A[NR, f] = $f } }

END { s = -2; t = 4;
    for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++ ) {
        printf "%s %s %s\n", r, A[s, 2], A[t, 3]
        s++; t++
    }
}

$ awk -f t.awk infile
1  IV
2  V
3  VI
4 a 
5 b 
6 c
```

Can easily be extended to the more general case of N rows by calculating initial values for `s` and `t`.

```
$ cat newinfile
1 a I
2 b II
3 c III
4 d IV
5 e V
6 f VI
7 g VII
8 h VIII
9 i IX

$ awk -f t.awk newinfile
1  IV
2  V
3  VI
4 a VII
5 b VIII
6 c IX
7 d 
8 e 
9 f
```